# After muting - can't unmute

Tags: android, mute

Muting works, but when I try unmute it doesn't work, I have spent enought time figuring it by myself, but with no luck. Here are the methods I use:

```
public void MuteAudio(Context context){
    AudioManager mAlramMAnager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        mAlramMAnager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
        mAlramMAnager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
        mAlramMAnager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
        mAlramMAnager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
        mAlramMAnager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
    } else {
        mAlramMAnager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);
        mAlramMAnager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, true);
        mAlramMAnager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
        mAlramMAnager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
        mAlramMAnager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
    }
}

public void UnMuteAudio(Context context){
    AudioManager mAlramMAnager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        mAlramMAnager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE, 0);
        mAlramMAnager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE, 0);
        mAlramMAnager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE,0);
        mAlramMAnager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE, 0);
        mAlramMAnager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE, 0);
    } else {
        mAlramMAnager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
        mAlramMAnager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, false);
        mAlramMAnager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
        mAlramMAnager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
        mAlramMAnager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it showing error? Because the code looks pretty good to me.

Comment: It doesn't, I can mute but I can not unmute. That is the problem.

Comment: You code looks good. I cannot find any issues in this code given above. But I'll look for solution and will get back to you. Meanwhile just make sure your unmute method is getting called.

Comment: If everything is ok with the code above then something is wrong with method calling it. Ok, thank you for help!